# Kotlin pass through constructor parameters to parent without declaring in child

Tags: kotlin, inheritance, constructor

My use case:
I have a large number of POJO models that are different types of requests for a third-party API. All of them have several common fields and a couple unique ones.

I was hoping to build something that conceptually looks like this

```
class RequestBase(
  val commonField1: String,
  val commonField2: String,
  ...
  val commonFieldX: String
)

class RequestA(
  val uniqueFieldA: String
): RequestBase()

class RequestB(
  val uniqueFieldB: String
): RequestBase()

fun main() {
  val requestA = RequestA(
    commonField1 = "1",
    commonField2 = "2",
    ...
    uniqueFieldA = "A"
  )
}
```

I can of course override the common fields in every child request and then pass them to the parent constructor, but this ends up producing a lot of boilerplate code and bloats the model. Are there any options I can explore here?

Comment: @Sweeper I'm sorry, I don't understand your question.

Comment: Oops I just noticed my typo. I meant "Do the properties have to be `val`s?"

Comment: @Sweeper no, they can be vars. I'm in full control of the model and can build whatever, I'm just trying to come up with something that will be easier for devs to look at later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice that what you are doing in the parentheses that follow a class declaration is not "declaring what properties this class has", but "declaring the parameters of this class' primary constructor". The former is just something you can do "along the way", by adding `var` or `val`.

Each class can have its own primary constructor that take any number and types of parameters that it likes, regardless of what class its superclass is. Therefore, it is not unreasonable to have to specify all the parameters of the constructor:

```
open class RequestBase(
  val commonField1: String,
  val commonField2: String,
  ...
  val commonFieldX: String
)

class RequestA(
  // notice that the parameters for the inherited properties don't have the
  // "val" prefix, because you are not declaring them in the subclass again.
  // These are just constructor parameters.
  commonField1: String, 
  commonField2: String,
  ...
  commonFieldX: String,
  val uniqueFieldA: String,
): RequestBase(
  commonField1,
  commonField2,
  ...
  commonFieldX,
)
```

If you find this unpleasant, there are a bunch of ways to work around this.

One way is to use composition and delegation - create an interface having the common properties. The specific requests' primary constructors will take a `RequestBase` and their unique properties, and implement the interface by delegating to the `RequestBase`:

```
interface Request {
    val commonField1: String
    val commonField2: String
    val commonFieldX: String
}

open class RequestBase(
    override val commonField1: String,
    override val commonField2: String,
    override val commonFieldX: String
): Request

class RequestA(
    val requestBase: RequestBase,
    val uniqueField: String
): Request by requestBase
```

This allows you to access `someRequestA.commonFieldX` directly, without doing `someRequestA.requestBase.commonFieldX`, but to create a `RequestA`, you need to create a `RequestBase` first:

```
RequestA(
    RequestBase(...),
    uniqueField = ...
)
```

Another way is to change your properties to `var`s, give them default values, and move them out of the constructor parameters:

```
open class RequestBase {
    var commonField1: String = ""
    var commonField2: String = ""
    var commonFieldX: String = ""
}

class RequestA: RequestBase() {
    var uniqueField: String = ""
}
```

Then to create an instance of `RequestA`, you would just call its parameterless constructor, and do an `apply { ... }` block:

```
RequestA().apply {
    commonField1 = "foo"
    commonField2 = "bar"
    commonFieldX = "baz"
    uniqueField = "boo"
}
```

The downside of this is of course that the properties are all mutable, and you have to think of a default value for every property. You might have to change some properties to nullable because of this, which might not be desirable.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try both options and talk to the team about what is most maintainable.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it with constructors of base class. Without constructors it's possible:

```
open class RequestBase {
    lateinit var commonField1: String
    lateinit var commonField2: String
    ...
    lateinit var commonFieldX: String
}

class RequestA(
    val uniqueFieldA: String
): RequestBase()

class RequestB(
    val uniqueFieldB: String
): RequestBase()

fun main() {
    val requestA = RequestA(
        uniqueFieldA = "A"
    ).apply {
        commonField1 = "1"
        commonField2 = "2"
        ...
        commonFieldX = "X"
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this really a use case of `lateinit`? In my view, `lateinit` is only used when you *definitely* know that the property is going to be initialised, but the compiler doesn't. In this case, it is very possible that someone can forget to set one of the properties in the `apply` block. I would instead set a default value for the properties, or make them nullable and set `null` as the default value.